# Offline map (.obf file) in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, offline

I want to include a MapView in my Application. I have been playing around with the Google Api a bit and it worked quite well.

But now I want to have a map completely offline. I know there are a lot of possibilities to do this.

The problem is that I have maps with .obf extension not zip. It should be possible to zoom in and out and to set markers at specific locations.

I know that there are things like Osmdroid. But I can't find any tutorial to load .obf file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look at OsmAnd.

It works with .obf format and provides you offline navigation.

[OsmAnd](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToPrepareYourOwnDataToUseOffline)